# QT SIGSEGV при создании окна из трея на Ubuntu

Tags: c++, linux, qt, ubuntu, qt5

Коротко говоря - у меня есть иконка в трее. При клике по пункту меню этой иконки я хочу создавать и отображать окно, однако получаю SIGSEGV при отображении окна.

**test.pro**

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += c++11

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any Qt feature that has been marked deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
    application.cpp \
    main.cpp \
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
    application.h \
    mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
    mainwindow.ui

TRANSLATIONS += \
    test_en_US.ts

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

**application.h**

```
#ifndef APPLICATION_H
#define APPLICATION_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QApplication>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QSystemTrayIcon>

class Application : public QApplication
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Application(int argc, char *argv[]);

public slots:
    void testShow();

private:
    QSystemTrayIcon* tray;
    MainWindow* w;
};

#endif // APPLICATION_H
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**application.cpp**

```
#include "application.h"
#include <QAction>
#include <QMenu>
#include <QStyle>

Application::Application(int argc, char *argv[])
    : QApplication(argc, argv)
{
    QAction* action = new QAction("test");

    QMenu* menu = new QMenu();
    menu->addAction(action);

    tray = new QSystemTrayIcon();
    tray->setIcon(menu->style()->standardIcon(QStyle::SP_ComputerIcon));
    tray->setContextMenu(menu);
    tray->show();

    connect(action, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(testShow()));

    // But this line works!!!
    //action->trigger();
}

void Application::testShow()
{
    w = new MainWindow();
    w->show(); // Error here
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "application.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Application a(argc, argv);

    return a.exec();
}
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

**mainwindow.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Ну или просто [ссылка на архив](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LXWFtrGfJij92iFOR2OCUzNfvjy6Uc5B/view?usp=sharing) с исходниками.

Ошибка вылетает в `application.cpp` около `w->show();`. Тем не менее, если я сам программно "кликаю" по этому пункту меню (`application.cpp`, `action->trigger();`), то все супер.

У меня убунта 19.10. Насколько я знаю, линукс поднимает эту ошибку когда одна программа залазит в память другой (что странно в данном случае). На виндовсе у меня этот код работает нормально. Что не так?

Comment: А вас не смущает утечка памяти?

Comment: SIGSEGV - это обычно, когда вы обращаетесь к несуществующей памяти

Comment: УМВР (*Qt 5.11.3, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc-9.2.0*)... да и на глаз ошибку не вижу...

Comment: @ヒミコ Я чищу память в деструкторах в другом проекте с такой же проблемой. Этот я собрал, чтобы можно минимум кода показать людям.

Comment: Похоже, ошибка возникает даже просто при попытке получить `arguments()` из `Application`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оккей... Это невероятно тупо, но это сработало. Просто в конструкторе `Application` я заменил параметры с `int argc, char *argv[]` на `int& argc, char**& argv`, т.е. просто передаю входные данные по ссылке. Теперь все работает.